# reverseBytes using Bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

- reverseBytes - reverse bytes
- Example: reverseBytes(0x0123456789abcdef) = 0xefcdab8967452301
- Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

I'm required to solve the above problem. There is no limit on no. of operators. I already have a different solution to this. But I would like to know what's the problem with the following solution I came up with? Thank you.

```
long reverseBytes(long x) {
    int a = x; //Get first bytes, first 8 bits
    int b = (a >> 8); //Get 2nd byte
    int c = (b >> 8); //3rd byte
    int d = (c >> 8); //4th
    int e = (d >> 8); //5th
    int f = (e >> 8); //6th
    int g = (f >> 8); //7th
    int h = (g >> 8); //8th
    a = a & 0xFF; //Remove the rest except LSB byte
    b = b & 0xFF; // same
    c = c & 0xFF;
    d = d & 0xFF;
    e = e & 0xFF;
    f = f & 0xFF;
    g = g & 0xFF;
    h = h & 0xFF;
    return ( (a << 56) + (b << 48) + (c << 40) + (d << 32) + (e << 24) + (f << 16) + (g << 8) + (h) );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your solution and find out whats wrong yourself?

Comment: Ofcourse. I wouldn't know this was wrong had I not tried it. I simply extracted every byte into an integer. Then summed them up after shifting to their specific position. The last byte (LSB) becomes first (MSB)...and so on.

Comment: The way you're extracting bytes already doesn't work (and shouldn't be used, too serial) since it relies on the entire `long` fitting in an `int`

Comment: @harold I thought about that. But replacing all ints' with long did'nt help :/

Comment: why language are you using? I'm tagging C. You need to fix it if you're not using C

Answer (score 0):

1. For practical application, you can use library function [bswap64()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?apropos=0&sektion=9&query=bswap64&manpath=FreeBSD%207.0-current&format=html)
2. For student practice, you needed write a simple loop like:

   ```
   unsigned long reverseBytes(unsigned long x) {
     unsigned long rc;
     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++, x >>= 8) 
       rc = (rc << 8) | (unsigned char)x;
     return rc; 
   }
   ```

Comment: who said that the OP is using FreeBSD? `bswap64()` isn't available in all platforms

Answer (score 0):

To your last comment, after a change of int to long as advised by harold, the code does work right, as can be seen by running the following main function:

```
int main()
{
    long x,b;
    x = 0x7285358428453790;
    b = reverseBytes(x);
    printf("b: %lx",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34454748)